# iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser namespace Doesn't Resolve

Tags: asp.net-mvc, namespaces, itext

I’m trying to read PDF files using iTextSharp.  Examples cite the iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser namespace.  However it doesn’t resolve after downloading the latest version from SourceForge and adding the iTextSharp reference to an MVC 3.5 project.

Is the namespace obsolete?
Is there a different version I should download?

Comment: The namespace is correct. Are you sure you are using iTextSharp 5.4.4: http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/itextsharp/iTextSharp-5.4.4/

Answer (score 0):

I tried it for my web application and it was showing some reference error for iTextSharp.Text.Pdf.Parser. So To solve try this:-

Remove all the references related to iTextSharp and download & extract .zip (latest 5.4.5).
And include iTextSharp.dll (5.4.5) as a reference. Check it